# Detect an invalid keyword argument

Tags: python, arguments, keyword

I have the following function:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
  if not kwargs:
    # No keyword arguments? It's all right. Set defaults here...
  elif ('start_index' or 'end_index') in kwargs:
    # Do something here...
  else:
    # Catch unexpected keyword arguments
    raise TypeError("%r are invalid keyword arguments" % (kwargs.keys())
```

**Question:**

I want to make sure that the only valid keyword arguments are `start_index` or `end_index`. Anything else will raise an error, even if mixed with the valid ones. What's the cookbook recipe to make sure that only `start_index` or `end_index` are accepted? Yes, I'm looking for a cookbook recipe but I'm not sure how to search for it. I'm not sure if using an `if-elif-else` structure is the correct way to do it either.

Comment: Are you aware that `('start_index' or 'end_index') in kwargs` does not do what you probably want? `string1 or string2` will yields one of the two strings (most likely `string1`), so your example will _never_ check `'end_index' in kwargs`. Something like `for kw in ('start_index', 'end_index'): if kw in kwargs ...` would do the trick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, Here's an alternative that still uses `**kwargs`.

```
def foo(**kwargs):
  start_index = kwargs.pop('start_index', STARTINDEX_DEFAULT)
  end_index = kwargs.pop('end_index', ENDINDEX_DEFAULT)
  if kwargs:
    # Catch unexpected keyword arguments
    raise TypeError("%r are invalid keyword arguments" % (kwargs.keys())
  # Do something here...
```

*But*, you shouldn't want to use this when you don't absolutely need it, use regular parameters with default values (as in Roman Bodnarchuk's answer).

Cases when you might need this is when you also want to use `*args`, and need a way to distinguish the keyword arguments from arbitrarily man positional arguments.  using `**kwargs` this way *forces* the keyword arguments to be passed as keywords; A positional argument can never find its way into `**kwargs`.

Another reason is so that you can *really* distinguish between a default and an explicit parameter which happens to be the default.  `None` is often used as a default value for arguments to indicate "the argument doesn't apply", but sometimes you actually need to interpret the `None` as something other than a default.  Checking for the presence or absence of a key in the `**kwargs` dict can accurately distinguish between these cases.  (An alternative is to create an instance of a subclass of `object` whos sole purpose is to be the default value of a specific argument to that specific function)

Answer (score 13):

Why do you need `**kwargs` here? Just

```
def foo(start_index=None, end_index=None):
```

and Python will perform all validation for you.

Comment: +1 for reminding me of this. I forgot to make it obvious in my question that using `**kwargs` was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `**kwargs`, I'd write that like:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    # Define default values for all keys
    args = {'start_index': 0, 'end_index': -1}

    # Get the keys passed in that aren't in args
    extraargs = set(kwargs) - set(args)
    if extraargs:
        raise TypeError("Invalid arguments: %s" % list(extraargs))

    # Overwrite the default values with the passed-in values
    args.update(kwargs)

    # Now, do stuff with the values in args
```

But all of that is a complicated, slow way to duplicate built-in functionality. Don't do that unless you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

In any case getting keys from a dict is as easy as using `.get` e.g.

`kwargs.get('WIDTH',500)`

this way if it doesn't find WIDTH as a key you get 500.